# Docker, MySQL - Error 1045, Access denied for use root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've just started learning docker and I want to dockerize my Golang project but I get this error when I want to use MySQL: `Error 1045: Access denied for use 'root'@'192.168.32.3' (using password: YES)`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  x-media-service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=db"
      - "DB_NAME=xmedia"
      - "DB_PASS=password"
      - "JWT_SECRET=secret"
      - VIDEO_DIR=/data/movies
      - MOVIES_SUB_DIR=/data/sub
    volumes:
      - /home/user/Movies:/data/movies
      - /home/user/Movies/sub:/data/sub

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 6603:3306
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
```

Comment: Can you try adding  "command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" in your db service?

Comment: @MdHasanIbrahim same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Go code I'm using root user to login into MySQL. I changed `DB_PASS` in `x-media-service` to same as `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in `db` service. Now everything is working.